# Ajax function triggered from another ajax function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on a script that copies a row ID from one table and creates a new table on the page with all rows that have been selected via checkbox in order to create a comparison table of selected results and I've run into an issue with the synergy between two of my ajax calls.

When the following row is created in the original table, the class that is assigned to the `<a>` element of that row triggers an ajax call which then populates a modal that shows up on the page with additional information.

This is the line

`echo "<td><a id='$id' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>".$results['provider_name']."</a>";`

When the modal is triggered this way, the information populates just fine.

Now, within the script that populates the new table, I make a call to another separate script which re queries the selected row ids and sets the html.

Here is that portion of the script :

```
 $('.compareCheck:checked').each(function(){
            var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : 'compare.php', //query 
            data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // passing id via ajax
            dataType: "json",
            success : function(data){
                var row = "<tr class='removeRow'>";
                row += "<td>" + data.provider_num + "</td>";

//HERE IS WHERE THE RE-CREATION OF THE MODAL CALL GOES \/

                row += "<td><a id='" + ele_id + "' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>" + data.provider_name + "</a></td>";

                row += "<td style='text-align:right;'>$" + formatNumber(data['233_net_charity_care']) + "</td>";
                row += "<td style='text-align:right;'>$" + formatNumber(data['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']) + "</td>";
                row += "<td style='text-align:right;'>$" + formatNumber(data['301_cost_of_uncomp_care']) + "</td>";
                row += "<td style='text-align:right;'>" + ((data['233_net_charity_care']/data['301_cost_of_uncomp_care'])*100).toFixed(1) + "%</td>";
                row += "<td style='text-align:right;'>" + ((data['291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts']/data['301_cost_of_uncomp_care'])*100).toFixed(1) + "%</td>";
                row += "</tr>";
                $("#compareTable > tbody").append(row);
              }
            });
              });
```

As you can see in my current implementation I am using the `ele_id` var, but I have also tried things like `data.id` and `data['id']`. All of which trigger the modal but produce no results from the php script.

Here are my two php scripts:

Script A: Populating the modal - (modalquery.php)

```
<?php
require_once("link_costreport_2013.php");
$id = $_POST['post_id'];
$modalquery = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM s10 WHERE id = :id");
$modalquery->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$modalquery->execute();
$modalresults = $modalquery->fetch();
print_r("<h4>State: ".$modalresults['state']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>City: ".$modalresults['city']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Street: ".$modalresults['street']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Zip: ".$modalresults['zip']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>County: ".$modalresults['county']."</h4>");
?>
```

and script B - The script that turns the re-query into values for the new comparison table (compare.php)

```
<?php
include_once('functions.php');
include_once('link_costreport_2013.php');
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
    $id = $_POST['post_id'];
}
    $query = $link->prepare("SELECT * 
                FROM `s10`
                            WHERE `id` = :id");
    $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

also in case it helps, here is my script for turning the `.push` class into a trigger for the ajax call which returns the modal content.

```
$(function(){
            $('.push').click(function(){
            var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');

            $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
             url : 'modalquery.php', // in here you should put your query 
            data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                   // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
             success : function(r)
             {
                // now you can show output in your modal 
              $("#provmodal .modal-body").html(r).promise().done(function(){
              $("#provmodal").modal('show');  
                           });
             }
               });
              });
          });
```

I'm new to using ajax and jquery in this fashion so any insight at all would be excellent.

thanks in advance

:EDIT: Here is the output from `json_encode($results)` when ID = 1

`{"id":"1","report_record_num":"548598","provider_num":"381301","provider_name":"COTTAGE GROVE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL","street":"1515 VILLAGE DRIVE","city":"COTTAGE GROVE","county":"LANE","state":"OR","zip":"97424-9700","cbsa":"21660","urban_or_rural":"Rural","ownership_type":"Voluntary, Nonprofit, Church","divider":"","divider2":"","1_cost_to_charge_ratio":"0.703459","2_net_rev_from_mcd":"3920096","3_recieve_sup_mcd_payments":"Y","4_include_if_yes":"N","5_dsh_or_sup_payments":"84890","6_medicaid_charges":"6192717","7_medicaid_cost":"4356323","8_dif_net_rev_and_cost":"351337","9_schip_net_rev":"0","10_stnd_alone_schip_charges":"0","11_stnd_alone_schip_cost":"0","12_diff_schip_rev_and_cost":"0","13_net_rev_from_state_local":"0","14_charge_under_state_law":"0","15_state_local_program_cost":"0","16_dif_between_net_rev_and_cost":"0","17_private_grants_and_donations":"6886","18_gov_grants":"0","19_tot_unreim_cost_mcd_schip_gov":"351337","201_tot_init_charity_for_uninsured":"593922","202_tot_init_charity_for_insured":"1072203","203_tot_init_charity_all":"1666125","211_cost_of_init_charity":"417800","212_cost_of_init_charity":"754251","213_cost_of_init_charity":"1172051","221_partial_pmt_charity_pat":"4385","222_partial_pmt_charity_pat":"8868","223_partial_pmt_charity_pat":"13253","231_net_charity_care":"413415","232_net_charity_care":"745383","233_net_charity_care":"1158798","241_charges_beyond_los_inc":"N","251_charges_beyond_los_lim":"0","261_total_bed_debts":"0","271_medicare_bad_debts":"79275","281_non_medicare_bad_debts":"-79275","291_cost_of_non_mcr_bad_debts":"-55767","301_cost_of_uncomp_care":"1103031","311_cost_of_unreim_and_uncomp":"1454368"}`

:EDIT2: Ok, so I went back and took some pics of what is happening. Somehow my modal text is not appearing in the second table `<a class="push">` element. Here are the pics:

!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaQss.jpg) - This is in the first table
 !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLcJl.jpg) - This is what happens in the second when the same link is pressed. I believe it's not triggering the ajax .push call.

Comment: Can you show us the JSON you get back from your initial script?

Comment: @jonmrich ok I think this is what you are looking for: 

its in my original post

Comment: Okay...I've re-read your question a bunch of times and I'm still not quite sure what the problem is. You're getting back valid JSON and seem to be parsing it fine. What's not working exactly?

Comment: @jonmrich I have edited the original post with the images of what is occuring.

Comment: "This is what happens in the second when the same link is pressed" which link. I'm not following what triggers the first image and what triggers the second.

Comment: @jonmrich
`<a id='$id' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>` is the first link, it is created in php and triggers the modal in the first image. 

`row += "<td><a id='" + ele_id + "' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>" + data.provider_name + "</a></td>";` is apart of my script that creates the rows in the second table, the `<a>` element is pretty much identical to the first link on the same page, yet when I click it, it does not produce a result in the modal, the modal triggers, but no data is inside of it. The result of this is in the second image.

Comment: The provider name column in the background contains individual rows in which the provider name is the link that triggers these modals on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74451/discussion-between-jonmrich-and-habitat).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$(document).on('click','.push',function(){
```

For:

```
$('.push').on('click', function(){
```

In the first case the event handler is added to every element with the "push" class that is present in the DOM at the moment of the execution of the "click" function. The second case, the one wich uses the "on" function, it adds the event handler to the elements already present and those which are not yet in the DOM, those which you create after the execution of the adition like the ones you add to the table.

Wish i make my self clear, i am trying to improve my english.

Comment: I think you mean `$(document).on('click','.push',function () {//..`

Comment: No need, the one i posted should work as the one you re saying i think.

Comment: no, you are wrong,what you posted is nearly equivalent to `$('.push').click (function () {//...` and will not apply to new elements dynamically created after the declaration